# Скрытие группы столбцов в GridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Создал форму с группой чекбоксов(36 штук). Необходимо, чтобы при выборе любого чекбокса его название сохранялось в лист ToHide. Затем циклом я хочу скрыть все столбцы в GridView, которые есть в листе. Вот код, который я написал:

```
private void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox box = new CheckBox();

            if (box.Checked)
            {               
                Data.ToHide.Add(box.Text);
            }
        }
```

Но он не работает потому, что при каждом вызове события создаётся новый чекбокс, который никак не относится к выбранному. Не могу придумать как исправить код, чтобы все работало правильно.

Comment: если у вас `OnCheckedChanged`  навешен на чекбокс, то используйте `sender`. `CheckBox box = sender as CheckBox;`

Comment: Конечно, новый чекбокс создавать не нужно - приведите sender к типу CheckBox